# Can't access BIOS on Dell Optiplex 9029 with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, bios

I have Ubuntu and Windows installed on separate partitions on a Dell Optiplex. The dual boot worked fine for a while but recently when I start the machine up it skips the Dell screen and goes straight to loading Ubuntu. I've tried a few suggestions to access the BIOS or the boot menu but none have them have worked..I'm not sure what caused this, since the only thing I've done recently is install MATLAB and Illustrator on the Windows partition which I can't imagine would affect the startup settings.  We also had a blackout which caused the computer to lose power a couple weeks back but I think it did work following that. Anyone have a similar issue or know what might be causing this?

Comment: Depending on your hardware configuration, the Dell screen and the BIOS settings might be accessible using a particular display connection only, especially if your system has both an integrated iGPU and a more powerful discrete GPU card. A blackout might have caused loss of BIOS settings (if the CMOS memory battery on the motherboard is starting to die), and if there is a BIOS setting that decides which GPU is the "primary" one, it might also decide which GPU will show the Dell screen and the BIOS menus. Try temporarily plugging the display to the other GPU to see if you can see the BIOS then.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the comment. It only has one GPU and it is integrated ( Core i7-4770 with HD Graphics 4600) but weirdly the display port I was using did stop working so I had to switch to the second port. Do you think it could still be an issue with the display? Would it be worth getting a vga cord?